# How to animate SKNodes or SKSpriteNode to collide and bounce?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I have a few questions regarding animating SKNodes and or SKSpriteNodes. First one is how do i get them to move once the view loads? How do i make them collide and bounce off each other and go into the other direction. I am using an SKScene for this. Also is there a way to group SKSriteNodes with SKLabels?

I have:

```
 #import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

//constants for the collision bitmap
static const uint32_t classicCategory = 1 << 0;
static const uint32_t arcadeCategory = 1 << 1;
static const uint32_t frenzieCategory = 1 << 2;

@interface HomeScene : SKScene <SKPhysicsContactDelegate> {

BOOL isSoundActionCompleted;
}

@end
```

Here is where I declare the SKSpriteNodes

```
    SKSpriteNode *classicMode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bubble.png"];
    classicMode.size = CGSizeMake(130, 130);
    classicMode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2+50);
    classicMode.name = @"classicMode";
    [self addChild:classicMode];

    SKLabelNode *classicTitle = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Noteworthy"];
    classicTitle.text = @"Classic";
    classicTitle.fontSize = 25;
    classicTitle.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter;
    classicTitle.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter;
    classicTitle.fontColor = [SKColor darkGrayColor];
    classicTitle.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2+50);
    classicTitle.name = @"classicTitle";
    [self addChild:classicTitle];
```

The other one here

```
    SKSpriteNode *arcadeMode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bubble.png"];
    arcadeMode.size = CGSizeMake(130, 130);
    arcadeMode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2+68, self.size.height/2-65);
    arcadeMode.name = @"arcadeMode";
    [self addChild:arcadeMode];

    SKLabelNode *arcadeTitle = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Noteworthy"];
    arcadeTitle.text = @"Arcade";
    arcadeTitle.fontSize = 25;
    arcadeTitle.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter;
    arcadeTitle.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter;
    arcadeTitle.fontColor = [SKColor darkGrayColor];
    arcadeTitle.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2+68, self.size.height/2-65);
    arcadeTitle.name = @"arcadeTitle";
    [self addChild:arcadeTitle];
```

Collision:

```
    //collision  and contact detection
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = arcadeCategory;

    //physics and collision detection
    classicMode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:classicMode.size];
    classicMode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;  //no gravity
    classicMode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = arcadeCategory;

    arcadeMode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:arcadeMode.size];
    arcadeMode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;  //no gravity
    arcadeMode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = classicCategory;
```

And collision detection:

```
    //collision detection
    classicMode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = classicCategory;
    classicMode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = arcadeCategory;
    classicMode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = arcadeCategory;

    arcadeMode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = arcadeCategory;
    arcadeMode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = classicCategory;
    arcadeMode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = classicCategory;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) first problem in your code is that two static bodies never collide make them dynamic. so make atleast one or both bodies dynamic.

2)secondly for linear movement use body.physicsBody.velocity property with dynamic body bodies.

3)change your bitmask categories 
    classicMode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = classicCategory;
    classicMode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = arcadeCategory;
    classicMode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = arcadeCategory;

```
arcadeMode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = arcadeCategory;
```

remember that contactTestBitMask uses in spritekit when two bodies contact or collide with each other and collisionBitMask is used to prevnet them to overlap or pass through each other

i cut  arcadeMode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = classicCategory;
    arcadeMode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = classicCategory;
 from your code because you alreay define it in
    classicMode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = classicCategory;
    classicMode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = arcadeCategory;
    classicMode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = arcadeCategory; so no need to redfine it

use contactTestBitMask and collisionBitMask  only once when you want two category interact with each other

4) handle all your collision and collision logic inside didbegincontact and didEndContact